# Variables inside of selectors

Tags: jquery, string, variables

I saw a bunch of other threads that ask how you can combine variables with jQuery selectors, things like `$('.middle', $top)` to get whatever `$top` is if it's inside of `.middle`.

What I'm looking for is how to combine them like this:

```
var gallerymodal_number = $(this).attr('data-gallerynumber');
```

So say that `gallerymodal_number` ends up being a value of 2.

My code works if I just literally write out:

```
var galleryitem = '*[data-galleryitem="2"]';
```

But I need to get it via the variable above.

**So my question is how do I do something like this:**

```
var galleryitem = $('*[data-galleryitem="' + gallerymodal_number + '"]');
```

I just get an object returned with that particular code.

Comment: This should work...can you show a complete example of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var galleryitem = '*[data-galleryitem="' + gallerymodal_number + '"]';
```

All you are doing here is creating a string with the value `*[data-galleryitem="2"]`

To return an object you need to use your string as a jQuery selector:

```
var galleryitem = $('*[data-galleryitem="' + gallerymodal_number + '"]');
```

Or to make what you are currently doing a little clearer:

```
var selectorString = '*[data-galleryitem="' + gallerymodal_number + '"]';
var galleryitem = $(selectorString);
```

Comment: I could be wrong...But I think it can be assumed the OP is already doing this. From his post: My code works if I just literally write out: `var galleryitem = '*[data-galleryitem="2"]';`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I had actually apparently figured it out before posting, but I've updated my original question to reflect that I was trying to have the entire variable be like so `var galleryitem = $('*[data-galleryitem="' + gallerymodal_number + '"]');` - but when you add in the $() part wrapping it, things break. Maybe one of you could comment on why that breaks it? In other words, why you have to put @turnip 's `selectorString` into a variable, and then use that inside of the $() ? Also @mevius :)